# Q: Can mapstruct understand that an expression returns a String so that it can use my dateFormat I provide?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm trying to get Mapstruct to understand a source expression is a string that it can format into a java.util.LocalDate, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. I tried following the directions in the mapstruct documents.

```java
@Mapping(componentModel = "cdi", uses=DateMapper.class)
public abstract class RedactedClassName

@Mapping(target = "birthDate",
            expression = "java(fileLine.substring(redactedpackagename.Constants.BIRTH_DATE_START_POS, redatcedpackagename.Constants.BIRTH_DATE_END_POS))")
    abstract PersonBio fileLineToPersonBio(String fileLine);
```

with the following formatter

```java
public class DateMapper {

    public String asString(LocalDate date) {

        return date != null ? date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")) : null;
    }

    public LocalDate asDate(String date) {
        return date != null ? LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")) : null;
    }
}
```

creates

```java
    @Override
    PersonBio fileLineToPersonBio(String fileLine) {
        if ( fileLine == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        PersonBio personBio = new PersonBio();

        personBio.setBirthDate( fileLine.substring(redactedpackagename.Constants.BIRTH_DATE_START_POS, redactedpackagename.Constants.BIRTH_DATE_END_POS) );

        return personBio;
    }
```

Edit: I've altered this post a bit to what I think should work, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The type of your expression is not `LocalDate`, it's `String`. Try using it in a scratch Java file first until it works.

Comment: But birthDate is a localdate, sorry, forgot that doesn't really show here.

Comment: I updated the code to use a custom mapper, still doesn't seem to work as per mapstruct's instructions page: http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#invoking-other-mappers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the output of your java expression is a string you expect that mapstruct will call the asDate method of the DateMapper class ?

What you expect to have in the generated code is something like this:

```
...
personBio.setBirthDate( new DateMapper().asDate(fileLine.substring(redactedpackagename.Constants.BIRTH_DATE_START_POS, redactedpackagename.Constants.BIRTH_DATE_END_POS)));
..
```

You're right, it doesn't work. I don't know why...

Instead you can import the mapper and use it in your java expression, and check the input with StringUtils:

```
@Mapper(imports = {DateMapper.class, StringUtils.class})
public interface PersonBioMapper {

  @Mapping(target = "birthDate",
      expression = "java(new DateMapper().asDate(StringUtils.substring(fileLine, redactedpackagename.Constants.BIRTH_DATE_START_POS, redatcedpackagename.Constants.BIRTH_DATE_END_POS)))")
  PersonBio fileLineToPersonBio(String fileLine);
}
```

Another way (more readable ?) is like Filip say, do a custom mapping:

```
@Mapper
public interface PersonBioMapper {

  default PersonBio fileLineToPersonBio(String fileLine) {
    PersonBio personBio = new PersonBio();
    personBio.setBirthDate(new DateMapper().asDate(StringUtils.substring(fileLine,redactedpackagename.Constants.BIRTH_DATE_START_POS, redactedpackagename.Constants.BIRTH_DATE_END_POS)));

    return personBio;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MapStruct does not validate the expression at generation-time. This means that you have to make sure that your expression outputs a valid code.

I would try to approach the problem you are trying to solve from another side. Instead of using an expression use a custom mapping for it that would create the date from the string.

You can read more about the expression in the [Expressions](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions) section of the documentation.